# Tracing actions carried out by a particular process in Windows 7 and above

Tags: windows, process

I would like to know if there are methods to trace actions carried out by a particular process ?

An example is to track an installer making edits to a Windows Registry and adjusting the Firewall settings of a Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

[Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) is what you're looking for.

It allows you to track pretty much any action being performed (or even just tried) by running processes.